# How can I get this DELETE route to work in my products.js route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, routes

I'm having a problem getting my delete route working for removing a single product by grabbing it's _id (5e335c57bd37eb1dd4d99b1f) in Mongoose. I assumed that simply copying the update route and changing it around a bit would work. All the other routes work fine in Postman.

products.js

```js
const express = require("express"),
router = express.Router(),
Product = require("../models/product.model");

// Product list route
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    Product.find().then(products => {
        res.status(200).json(products);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(`Recieving products failed. Error details: ${err.message}`);
    });
})

// Product details route
router.get("/:product_id", function(req, res) {
    Product.findById(req.params.product_id).then(product => {
        res.status(200).json(product);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(`Recieving product details failed. Error details: ${err.message}`);
    });
})

// Product create logic route
router.post("/add", function(req, res) {
    let product = new Product(req.body);
    product.save().then(product => {
        res.status(200).json({"product": `Product added successfully. Created product details: ${product}`});
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(`Adding new product failed. Error details: ${err.message}`);
    });
})

// Product update route
router.put("/:product_id", function(req, res) {
    Product.findById(req.params.product_id).then(product => {
        product.name = req.body.name;
        product.description = req.body.description;
        product.price = req.body.price;
        product.stock = req.body.stock;

        product.save().then(product => {
            res.status(200).json(`Product updated! Updated product details: ${product}`);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send(`Update not possible. Error details: ${err.message}`);
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(404).send(`Product not found. Error details: ${err.message}`);
    });
})

// Product destroy route (NOT WORKING)
router.delete("/:product_id", function(req, res) {
    Product.find(req.params.product_id).then(product => {
        product.remove().then(product => {
            res.status(200).json(`Product deleted! Deleted product details: ${product}`);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send(`Delete not possible. Error details: ${err.message}`);
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(404).send(`Product not found. Error details: ${err.message}`);
    });
})

module.exports = router;
```

Error in Postman:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
 <pre>Cannot DELETE /products/5e335c57bd37eb1dd4d99b1f</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Does it work if you use ‘.findById()’ like you do in the update route, rather than ‘.find()’?

Comment: I'm getting the same error with ‘.findById()’ as well unfortunately

Comment: Do you get the same error when running it with `.findById()`?

Comment: Why you're not trying another method, I mean `findOneAndRemove`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find returns an array, and in array there is no remove() method. You need to use `findOne`. Also find doesn't throw an error when nothing found. So you had better to check if find returns null.

```js
router.delete("/:product_id", function(req, res) {
  Product.findOne(req.params.product_id)
    .then(product => {
      if (product) {
        product
          .remove()
          .then(product => {
            res.status(200).json(`Product deleted! Deleted product details: ${product}`);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send(`Delete not possible. Error details: ${err.message}`);
          });
      } else {
        res.status(404).send(`Product not found. Error details: ${err.message}`);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send(`Error details: ${err.message}`);
    });
});
```

Also you can shorten this code using findByIdAndDelete method like this:

```js
router.delete("/:product_id", function(req, res) {
  Product.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.product_id)
    .then(product => {
      if (product) {
        return res.status(200).json(`Product deleted! Deleted product details: ${product}`);
      } else {
        return res.status(404).send("Product not found");
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send(`Error details: ${err.message}`);
    });
});
```